# Executing a function. Unable to print the output

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, sql-server-2008

I recently came across the following FUNCTION in stackoverflow:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.UrlDecode(@url varchar(3072))
RETURNS varchar(3072)
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @count int, @c char(1), @cenc char(2), @i int, @urlReturn varchar(3072) 
    SET @count = Len(@url) 
    SET @i = 1 
    SET @urlReturn = '' 
    WHILE (@i <= @count) 
     BEGIN 
        SET @c = substring(@url, @i, 1) 
        IF @c LIKE '[!%]' ESCAPE '!' 
         BEGIN 
            SET @cenc = substring(@url, @i + 1, 2) 
            SET @c = CHAR(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@cenc, 1, 1) LIKE '[0-9]' 
                                THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(@cenc, 1, 1) as int) 
                                ELSE CAST(ASCII(UPPER(SUBSTRING(@cenc, 1, 1)))-55 as int) 
                            END * 16 + 
                            CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@cenc, 2, 1) LIKE '[0-9]' 
                                THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(@cenc, 2, 1) as int) 
                                ELSE CAST(ASCII(UPPER(SUBSTRING(@cenc, 2, 1)))-55 as int) 
                            END) 
            SET @urlReturn = @urlReturn + @c 
            SET @i = @i + 2 
         END 
        ELSE 
         BEGIN 
            SET @urlReturn = @urlReturn + @c 
         END 
        SET @i = @i +1 
     END 
    RETURN @urlReturn
END
GO


I am trying to pass the following URL as an input to get the decoded URL as output using the following command:

DECLARE @urlReturn nvarchar(3072);  
EXEC dbo.UrlDecode2 @url = 'https%3a%2f%2fin.mathworks.com';  
PRINT @urlReturn;  
GO
```

Initially tried the following:

```
exec dbo.UrlDecode2 @url = 'https%3a%2f%2fin.mathworks.com';
go
```

The function decoded the encoded parts in the URL. I am totally new to PL/SQL. Could someone tell me where I am going wrong and how to print the decoded URL.

Comment: Please format your code correctly. You can do it by indenting each line by 4 spaces, or highlighting the code, and pressing ctrl+k.

Comment: The code is so clearly SQL Server that I removed the PL/SQL tag.  If you are really using Oracle, you should get yourself another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Declare @URL varchar(500) 
Set @URL = dbo.UrlDecode2('https%3a%2f%2fin.mathworks.com')
```

Returns

```
https://in.mathworks.com
```

Or within a Select

```
Select URL = dbo.UrlDecode2('https%3a%2f%2fin.mathworks.com')
```